# Adding a BigDecimal to BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, addition

I can't get this to work. I have written notes that will hopefully explain what I'm attempting to do. The console outputs an error at the line `totalCost = totalCost.add(new BigDecimal(result));`

```
private void btn_motherboardActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    String cost = cb_motherboard.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //gets item from combobox. Makes a string
    Components.addElement(cost);// adds string to model
    lb_computer_components.setModel(Components);//sets model to jlist

    String result = cost.substring(cost.lastIndexOf('£') + 1);
    //creates a substring containing information after £ (for example 45.99)

    totalCost = totalCost.add(new BigDecimal(result));
    //totalcost is a public bigdecimal, i want to add 45.99 to it in this example

    String BD = totalCost.toString();
    //change the new totalcost to a string

    String stringTotal = n.format(BD);
    //format that string to a currency

    txt_total_computer.setText(stringTotal); 
    //output that string to a textfield

}
```

Comment: have you tried using prints to see the values of varibles to see where it fails?

Comment: Oh sorry, it starts like this Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at computer.INterface.btn_motherboardActionPerformed(INterface.java:2324)

Comment: And did you instantiate `totalCost` at all?  Or is it null, like the error suggests?

Comment: Which line? I don't see any line numbers above.

Comment: Most likely you're using the BigDecimal totalCost and it has not been initialized so you're getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Smutje the third sentence of the question tells us which line it is.

Comment: The instantiation of `totalCost` isn't even included in the snippet...

Comment: Uh, "NulLPointerException" means you have a null pointer (er, "reference").  There are only two references on that line, so it should be fairly easy to establish which one is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because `totalCost` is null, and then you're trying to use the object that it references.

What you should do is add this line to your class's constructor.

```
totalCost = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realise how to initialise the global variable version of bigdecimal. I hope my basic question wasnt too annoying.